# SvelteKit on Google Cloud Shell environment CORS error with Laravel

Tags: laravel, cors, google-cloud-run, sveltekit, google-cloud-shell

I'm trying to get SvelteKit working with a Laravel back end on Google Cloud Shell (using the terminal, cloud editor, and web preview feature). [Context: I'm just using Cloud Shell as a dev environment due to policies at my work preventing a local install on my corporate laptop. Will then be deploying to Google Cloud Run for production.]. I'm an experienced front end web dev but brand new to Svelte and SvelteKit.

I'm doing a simple AJAX request from SvelteKit to Laravel:

```
const response = await fetch(`https://8000-cs-<some ID number>-default.cs-europe-west1-onse.cloudshell.dev/api/my_route_here`); // Base URL taken from cloud shell web preview of the back end once it's running
```

I ran the front end in a Google Cloud Shell terminal with `npm run dev -- --host` (also tried `npm run preview -- --host`)
I ran the back end in a second terminal instance, with `php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000` and used the web preview feature in that to get the redirected cloud shell domain name (e.g. `https://8000-cs-<some ID number>-default.cs-europe-west1-onse.cloudshell.dev`) and hardcoded that into the front end before I built and ran it.

The request fails with a CORS error (status code "302 Found"). Prior to that the dev console shows errors like:

```
Access to internal resource at 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=<some code>&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fssh.cloud.google.com%2Fdevshell%2Fgateway%2Foauth&response_type=code&scope=email&state=<some code>' (redirected from 'https://5173-cs-<some code>-default.cs-europe-west1-onse.cloudshell.dev/manifest.json') from origin 'https://5173-cs-<some code>-default.cs-europe-west1-onse.cloudshell.dev' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

(Note the 5173 in that is the port I'm serving the front end on)

Given I'm using the correct URL for the backend (it shows the Laravel default page if I just paste it in the browser) and my Laravel CORS policy in config/cors.php is:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

];
```

I'm not sure how to fix this? Any ideas welcome thanks.